# Using Z3Py online to prove that the derivative of x^2 is 2x

Tags: z3

The code for the proof is

```
x, d = Reals('x d')
t = (simplify(simplify(((x + d)**2 - x**2)/d, som = True), mul_to_power=True))
print t
prove(Implies(d != 0, t == 2*x + d))
prove(Implies(d == 0, 2 * x + d == 2*x))
```

and the output is

```
(2·d·x + d2)/d
proved
proved
```

Please let me know if you know a more compact proof using Z3Py.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting approach. I wondered if one can use the epsilon-delta definition of limit and do a more direct proof in Z3. I coded it up using the Haskell bindings to Z3 here: http://gist.github.com/LeventErkok/5516651

Unfortunately, Z3 returns "Unknown" for the generated query, which is not surprising due to the need for quantifiers. It'd been really nice if z3 was able to prove this.

I've posted the SMT-Lib translation of the Haskell generated query here: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/igAt if anyone wants to take a peek. (Mechanical translation is not quite human-readable, but if you squint hard enough, you can follow its logic; especially if you compare it to the Haskell source.)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the calls to `simplify`. You can write

```py
x, d = Reals('x d')
t = ((x + d)**2 - x**2)/d
print t
prove(Implies(d != 0, t == 2*x + d))
prove(Implies(d == 0, 2 * x + d == 2*x))
```

It can also try it online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/gB5E).

BTW, we should not confuse this script with a formal proof that the derivative of `x^2` is `2x`. This kind of proof can be performed in proof assistants like [Coq](http://coq.inria.fr/). There, you define, for example, what a derivative is.

Your script is an informal proof (argument) that is assisted by an automated tool (Z3).
The assistant (Z3) is being used to automate calculations and prove/discharges some steps of your informal proof. There is nothing wrong with that, but we should not claim this is a formal proof like the ones performed using Coq, where every step is formalized in the system.